# Downloading files from Azure Blob Storage - Error: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: azure, ssis

I've just started working with Azure Blob Storage and I'm trying to download Blob Blocks to my local environment, without any success. the file names get copied, but no data is copied (i.e. the files are empty)

If I use the same settings with an upload task, then the files are copied.

The error I get from SSIS (SQL Server 2016 SP1 and VS 2015 professional) is:

> Error: Download task has stopped with exception: The given path's format is not supported.

Below are the properties of the download and upload, any ideas anyone?

cheers,
Anthony

[image: Azure Blob Download Properties]

[image: Azure Blob Upload Properties]

Comment: I forgot to mention the local directory is set by a variable so is exactly the same for both processes

Comment: We needed to recreate the BLOB storage container and all worked?

Answer (score 0):

I tested both of these tasks, and my setup of each of the tasks look pretty much identical to yours as far as slashes and backslashes go for the LocalDirectory, BlobContainer, BlobDirectory, etc. I did notice you have some variation in capitalization (e.g. DELTA vs Delta), but I tested that as well, and it was not case sensitive.  Because all of that looks perfect, I suspect there is an issue with permissions or the name of the files that it doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. That's what I thought but as we can upload the files and the files, that are downloaded, are created but empty then I'm fairly confident that it must be something other than local permissions. I will investigate further.

Comment: p.s. the event log shows the error being thrown as me and I can access the directories?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the backslashes in the expression that sets the variable value used for LocalDirectory, like this:

```
C:\\Temp\\Delta\\GoodsIn
```